# GetPrintQueues() return null using LocalPrintServer on Windows Service C#

Tags: c#, wpf, service, printing

I have the following scenario:

1. Windows Server 2008 R2;
2. Windows Service configured to run as a local user administrator;
3. Local printer installed.

The service needs to send a WPF object to local printer, but after create a System.Printing.LocalPrintServer object and I try to get a print queues using GetPrintQueues() method the System.Printing.PrintQueueCollection returns a null collection.

**The code:**

```
private void PrintDocument(string printerName, string documentName)
{
    try 
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        LocalPrintServer localPrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();

        PrintQueueCollection printQueues = localPrintServer.GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });

        if (printQueues == null)
            throw new Exception("PrintQueues is null");

        PrintQueue queue = printQueues.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(printerName)).FirstOrDefault();

        printDialog.PrintDocument(this, documentName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log
    }
}
```

**I tried use the same assembly to get print queues using a WindowsForm application and DONE! *Why don't work in Windows Service?***

Comment: Is the printer you are trying to print for installed for all users, or installed for a single user?